# how to process conditional if string is not various strings?

Tags: bash, conditional-statements

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

DATABASES=`ssh root@host "mysql -u root -e 'show databases;'"`;
for database in $(echo $DATABASES | tr ";" "\n")
do
    if [ "$database" -ne "information_schema" ]
    then
        # ssh root@host "mysqldump -u root ..."
        # rsync ...
    fi
done
```

Need exclude:

- Database
- information_schema
- sys

How to make 3 conditions in one "if"? in other languages use "or" or "||" but in bash is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In BASH you can use `@(str1|str2|str3)` inside `[[...]]` to compare against multiple string values:

```
if [[ $database != @(information_schema|Database|sys) ]]; then
   echo "execute ssh command"
fi
```

Comment: Make sure you `shopt -s extglob` in your script

Comment: Actually `extglob` isn't needed for evaluation in `[[...]]`

Answer (score 1):

Inside `[[ ... ]]` you can use `||` for OR and `&&` for AND conditions, for example:

```
if [[ $database != information_schema && $database != sys && $database != Database ]]
then
    # ssh root@host "mysqldump -u root ..."
    # rsync ...
fi
```

Another alternative is using a `case`:

```
case "$database" in
    information_schema|sys|Database) ;;
    *)
        # ssh root@host "mysqldump -u root ..."
        # rsync ...
        ;;
esac
```